# Html file not reading .js?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This question has been asked ~10^4 times, but hear me out that I've done my due dilligence in reading the solutions and seeing if their tweaks fix things (to no avail). I'm an amateur when it comes to JS/CSS/HTML but I'm learning. I am trying to implement this sticky navigation bar from [here](https://codepen.io/prvnbist/pen/GQMPZq) (also see [here](https://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/Sticky-Header-Navigation-Smooth-Scroll-jQuery.html)). My question isn't about their code, which appears to be fine.

When I implement it, my .html file doesn't seem to be using the `.js` script at all. None of the buttons respond, I don't get any errors, but everything in the `.css` and `.html` files otherwise are rendering fine. The head:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
...
</html>
```

The script.js should be in the correctly referenced directory.

Answer (score 2):

Answer (as I was writing this): The jquery script and the custom script were in the wrong order. :)